# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Hi all,

As you can see, the new design went live, congratulations on the official launch!

If you see any CSS/Styling issues, please start a new question for the bug report, and tag it with "Design" and "Bug." It will be a lot easier for me to track new questions than reading the comments replied to this thread. A note for IE6/IE7, while we try to make sure the site is functional for people using older browsers, we don't support them to the point of pixel perfectness.

The favicons may be cached by your browsers, to see the new ones, load the following URL in your browser's address bar and hard refresh.

http://sstatic.net/english/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/englishmeta/img/favicon.ico

Some tweaks I changed from the original mockup posted: I changed meta text to sans serif, also the comment text too. I agree with @nohat that a combination of modern and old may suit the site better. I've also changed some link colors to be more consistent.

Thank you for your helpful [design input](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/400/english-site-design), and also thanks to [Alex](http://www.retinart.net) for a great design. Congrats again!

P.S. I'll be hanging out in the [English Chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage) this week on and off. Feel free to send me feedback there too(although I still prefer bug reports to be posted here on Meta). The English chat room's theme design has been updated as well.

Comment: Wah. Just noticed that the rank privileges are now at non-beta levels, so I've lost a few abilities. Sniff.

Comment: WOW! What a beautiful awesome design! Thanks, Jin! Please do not listen to @Kyle. I like the caps in the title.

Comment: Just wanted to add a link to our lovely [404 image](http://english.stackexchange.com/dispageexistnotdoes) by [John Tenniel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Tenniel).

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the game, here, but I love the new design!

Answer (score 1):

I would request a minor change: the "accepted" checkmark does not contrast enough with the accept-trigger-checkmark (the checkmark you click on to mark an answer as accepted).  On my LCD screen, and with my minor colour-blindness, these two are indistinguishable. I think the "accepted" mark should stand out more, either by being a brighter colour or a darker shade.

Comment: @MrShiny, I'll tweak the contrast, thanks!

Comment: @Jin: Thanks! It's nice when feedback is acknowledged :)

Comment: @MrShiny, is this a problem on both the parent site and the meta site?

Comment: @jin: I posted a question (http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/425) which expands on this topic.  Can you post an answer there so that I can try accepting it? It won't let me accept my own.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance of getting a typeface for questions that isn't quite so hard to read? The extreme contrast between heavy and lightweight strokes produces pretty bad aliasing and jagged edges at 1024x768.

I'm sure an antique-y font was chosen for the aesthetic it provides, but it is impacting readability.

EDIT: ClearType fixes the issue. Thanks for the pointer!

Otherwise, thanks for the great work!

Comment: The text looks quite readable to me. It might help to post a screen capture.

Comment: can you tell me what OS/ver/browser you're on? I've tested in both OSX and Win7 the text seems quite readable to me. BTW, if you're on Windows, do you have  ClearType turned on? http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx

Comment: Oh, man, does ClearType make a difference. That's what I get for assuming it was on by default on not-my-main-computer.

Comment: know what you mean. Even though I found the fonts perfectly readable already, I checked and I hadn't had ClearType turned on. Turned it on, and hoo boy, talk about improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I find it a bit strange that a website dedicated to the proper use of English would choose a font that displays in all caps, it feels like the website is shouting at me. :(

I love the font used in the comments, and Georgia is really a stain for the eyes (in my personal opinion) and it does kind of go against proper English use when everything is capitalised.

I'd love to see that change, but I might be the only one..

---

EDIT:

After some careful checking, I've discovered that the Georgia font on my computer is in fact NOT the correct Georgia:

[image: incorrect font screenshot]

So my apologies on your choice of font, the real one is very, very nice and I give a 100% thumbs up to the new design! :)

Comment: -1. I like the CAPS in the heading.

Comment: I'm not talking about the heading, that's fine, that's great! the actual font of the website! The on eused in questions and answers!

Comment: Heh, I had to edit, please read edit :)

Comment: @kyle, np. I am curious about what OS you're using. I thought Georgia is one of the safest font to use for web since it comes with most OSes?

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks, I can see why you were less-than-thrilled with the redesign if that's what you were (are?) seeing.

Comment: I have since fixed the error, I am using Windows 7. It was a practical joke from my colleagues, very funny!

Answer (score 0):

I thoroughly enjoy *how heavy handed usage* of the quotation tick results in a rather [garish, visually frightening answer/question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5501/preposition-to-follow-copy-and-paste/5515#5515).