# New Design: Can we increase the contrast between certain items?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've noticed that some of the elements in the [new design](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/417/new-design-launched) don't contrast enough from their surroundings.

Example:
 - Hyperlinks are dark red, so dark that I have difficulty distinguishing them from black, especially on an LCD screen which isn't at the perfect precise viewing angle (from an angle the colours change slightly).
 - The accept-answer checkmark (which is clicked to select the accepted answer) and the accepted-answer checkmark are so similar that I can barely tell them apart.

For what it's worth I noticed the link problem on other SE sites as well.

Comment: Please note: the question is serious but the two answers I posted are for testing purposes.

Comment: Just noticed: hyperlinks on meta are not red.  They stand out a lot.  On the main site the hyerlinks are indistinguishable from black for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have lightened the gray check mark, and boosted the saturation of the green arrow a bit. Also made the red link(and visited color) a bit lighter. The changes  will be in the next deployment. For the arrows you may have to hard refresh in case your browser caches the old image sprite. Note: these changes are for the parent site, not Meta.

Answer (score 0):

This is a test answer

Answer (score 0):

This is another test answer for [testing](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/417/new-design-launched) the accept-answer flag on meta